# How can I apply a quantity limit to *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

Since the Limit filter is gone from Angular 2+, how can I apply a limit for a simple *ngFor statement?

```
<div *ngFor="#tweet of singleCategory">
  {{ tweet }}
</div>
```

I don't want the *ngFor statement to loop through all the elements of singleCategory, I want to limit it to just 2 results. I believe that it could be done with Custom Pipes but I don't know how to implement it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can do a filter or simply capture the index `#i=index` and add an `ngIf ` where `i < 2`

Comment: Documentation for the slice pipe can be found at https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818735/239168

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can either apply an ngIf on the element using the index:

```
<div *ngFor=" let tweet of singleCategory;  let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i<2">
        {{tweet}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want the wrapping div, check out [template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-tweet [ngForOf]="singleCategory" let-i="index">
    <div [ngIf]="i<2">
        {{tweet}}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Preferably you first/instead filter the elements in your component using filter to prevent unnecessary loops when displaying your data:

```
public get singleCategory() {
   return this.categories.filter((item, index) => index > 2 )
}
```

There is also the option of creating a pipe. (See the linked duplicate)

Comment: Shouldn't that last one be return index > 2

Comment: as of today the template syntax [is deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28), you should use `let tweet` instead of `#tweet`

Comment: Just one more option:

`<div *ngFor="let item of (model ? model.slice(0,2): [])" >`

Comment: Now in Angular4+ `<template>` is deprecated. Use `<ng-template>` or even `<ng-container>`.

Comment: Just if anyone explores an error with updating the model with the slice option, you could return a new array and splice this one: `<div *ngFor="let item of (list ? list.concat([]).slice(0, 2): [])">`

Comment: but.... if the length of the collection is 100,000, just because you `*ngIf` the inner content, won't angular still add 100,000 of the `div` to the document? Seems like this is not a good answer.

Comment: I like this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818677/how-can-i-limit-ngfor-repeat-to-10-items-in-angular-2

Comment: I find @georgeos gives the best solutions

Comment: @prespic functions in your template (`.slice(...`) are executed every change detection. Unless you're using `OnPush` your proposed option can cause performance issues. [more info here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)