# angular ngFor with condition

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular 4 application I need to use ngFor with less than conditon. I mean I do not want to show all the item of `sampleArray`, instead I want to display only first 10 items, just like in normal java script we have `i < sampleArray.length` or `i < 10`, etc these kind of conditions I want to use in ngFor, is it possible?

```
<li *ngFor="let a of sampleArray">
    <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: there already an answer for the same check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818677/how-can-i-limit-ngfor-repeat-to-10-items-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit ngFor repeat to 10 items in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818677/how-can-i-limit-ngfor-repeat-to-10-items-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 6):

You need to simply use slice.

```
<li *ngFor="let a of sampleArray | slice:0:9">
  <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
  <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<li *ngFor="let a of sampleArray;  let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i<2">
        <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
        <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Updated:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of sampleArray;  let i=index">
  <li *ngIf="i<11">
    <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Simplest and easiest one to understand.

Comment: Is it possible to use *ngIf="i<11" condition in the above <li> tag itself, instead putting separate <div> tag for i < 2 condition.