# ngIf list only on one section in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular8

I am using Angular8 and have an ngFor to display an array of people.

This is the Array

```
private myArray: {}[] =
    [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "description goes here",
        },
        {
            "serviceName": "name2",
            "description": "description goes here",
        }
    ]
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="content" *ngFor="let details of myArray">
    <h2>{{details.name}}</h2>
    <div class="description">{{details.description}}</div>

    <ul *ngIf="isName1">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a foreach loop which loops through the array and changes `isName1` to true if it is the first in the array.

```
this.myArray.forEach(s => {

  if(name === 'name1') {
    this.isName1 = true;
  }
});
```

What I am trying to do is to get the `ul` to only show for the first element but not the 2nd, yet it is coming up for both. Is there any way to achieve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **always** want to just apply the condition to first element, despite of the value, you can use [`first`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables), which is provided by angular in `*ngFor`. So there is then no need to use the `forEach` loop:

```html
<div class="content" *ngFor="let details of myArray; let first = first">
  <h2>{{details.name}}</h2>
  <div class="description">{{details.description}}</div>

  <ul *ngIf="first">
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
      <span>item1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
      <span>item2</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfnt2p?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks, I found this to work best. Is it also possible to use second and third if I want the next element to have another list?

Comment: Then I would suggest to look into the index of the items in the array, since ngFor just provides truthy values for first and last item in array.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using ng-template

The beauty of using  is it will not be shown in HTML (as inline or block element).

Sample Code:

```
<div class="content" *ngFor="let details of myArray">
    <h2>{{details.name}}</h2>
    <div class="description">{{details.description}}</div>

    <ul>
    <ng-template [ngIf]="isName1">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item1</span>
        </li>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="!isName1">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item2</span>
        </li>
      </ng-template>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="content" *ngFor="let details of myArray">
    <h2>{{details.name}}</h2>
    <div class="description">{{details.description}}</div>

    <ul *ngIf="details.name === 'name1'">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far i understand you want to limit items in ngfor here is and important link

[How can I limit ngFor repeat to some number of items in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818677/how-can-i-limit-ngfor-repeat-to-some-number-of-items-in-angular)

So your code will look like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let details of myArray;let i=index" >
<div class="content" *ngIf="i==0">
    <h2>{{details.name}}</h2>
    <div class="description">{{details.description}}</div>

    <ul >
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>item2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(name === 'name1')` to `if(s.name === 'name1')`

> s.name

Try like this:

```
this.myArray.forEach(s => {

  if(s.name === 'name1') {
    this.isName1 = true;
  }
});
```