# How to loop through array upto only some objects using ngFor in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I'm looping through an array which has 6 objects and using ngFor where I want to loop only up to 4 elements .. How Can I do that??

```
<div class="item active" *ngFor="#data of lengthArray">
 content 
</div>
```

In LengthArray I have 6 but how to loop up to 4 records only??

and also I want to loop from 4th record to 6th record in another div.. How can I start from 4th record??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html) with a *start* and *end* parameter. The start parameter is required and the end parameter is optional.

```
<div class="item active" *ngFor="#data of lengthArray | slice:start[:end]">
  content 
</div>
```

Comment: can we have condition inside ?like when data.index==1 then start should be 4 ?

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the index and then make it less then 4

```
<div class="item active" *ngFor="#data of lengthArray;i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i<=4">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't really tested the code but you can find a lot of examples here on stackoverflow, do more researching...

[Angular 2: how to apply limit to *ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388270/angular-2-how-to-apply-limit-to-ngfor/36388647)

More about filters...
[How to apply filters to *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you I applied condition same as above answer slice:[i+1]:[i+4] like that

Comment: this will create 4 outer <div> elements with <div>'s inside, and then an excess number of empty outer <div> elements

Answer (score 0):

> Simple solution:

```
<tr *ngFor=""let obj of ArrayogObjs;  let i=index">
        <td *ngIf="i<4">
            {{obj.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: this will create 4 <tr> elements with <td>'s inside, and then an excess number of empty <td> elements