# Limit the ngFor loop to two iterations

Tags: angular

How to limit the ngFor loop to only 2 iterations?
I want there to be only 2 'chat-window' tags that can be displayed.

```html
<div class="chat-window-container">
    <chat-window
            *ngFor="let box of windows; let i = index"
            [box]="box">
    </chat-window>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: how to apply limit to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388270/angular-2-how-to-apply-limit-to-ngfor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a duplicate of [Angular 2: how to apply limit to *ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388270/angular-2-how-to-apply-limit-to-ngfor)

You can use `Array.slice(...)` do something like that if you don't want to use `<template>`:

```
<div class="chat-window-container">
    <chat-window
            *ngFor="let box of (windows ? windows.slice(0,2): []); let i = index"
            [box]="box">
    </chat-window>
</div>
```

**EDIT** : show the last two boxes (eg.: if 3 or more boxes):

You simply have to enhance a bit the `Array.slice(...)` parameters to make them more dynamic. This way, you'll always show the two latest boxes.

```
<div class="chat-window-container">
    <chat-window
            *ngFor="let box of (windows ? windows.slice(windows.length-2,2): []); let i = index"
            [box]="box">
    </chat-window>
</div>
```

For example, if you have 4 boxes in `windows`, it will be the same that:

```
<div class="chat-window-container">
    <chat-window
            *ngFor="let box of (windows ? windows.slice(2,2): []); let i = index"
            [box]="box">
    </chat-window>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. 
However when I open a 3rd box I want this one to replace the first one. Do I need a function or I can do this in HTML?

Comment: @Floriane I just updated my answer with what you asked for :). This is a HTML way, but you also can do it from your component.

Comment: I do not understand why but when I test your solution with the .length-2 function. I can open the first 2 windows but then when I click to open another window, it closes the old windows. 
Do you know why ?

Comment: @Floriane I need some more code to really understand the behavior you encounter.

Comment: Ok I created a new question to better explain my problem. 'Open the last 2 discussion windows'
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to keep your template clean of slicing and prepare the data in the component itself:

```
public get windows(): Window[] {
    return this.windows.slice(0,2);
}
```

or give the getter method another name, if you don't want to mix it up with existing getters in your component.

Comment: Upvote for the how to keep the template clean comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Simple soultion:

```
<div *ngFor=""let tran of transactiondata;  let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i<2">
        {{tran.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="chat-window-container">
    <template *ngFor="let box of windows; let i = index">
        <chat-window [box]="box" *ngIf="i < 2">
        </chat-window>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, you can't bind two structural directives to the same element. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: Not a really efficient answer, considering that if you have 1000 elements and you only want to display 2, you will still loop the whole collection